# Circuit component whose voltage is proportional to the third or higher derivative of the charge

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, voltage, inductance

I noticed that the ideal circuit components' voltages are all directly proportional to a certain derivative of the charge:

Capacitor: $V = \frac{1}{C}Q(t)$
Resistor: $V = RQ'(t)$
Inductor: $V = LQ''(t)$

Are there any other circuit components that are proportional to a higher derivative of the charge, such as $V = kQ'''(t)$?

Would it even be possible for such a component to exist?

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is a [Josephson junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephson_effect).

Answer (score 1):

I am an electronics engineer, we had courses related to many circuit components. We have seen higher order circuits, but the reason is different. Curently I do not remember a component as you mentioned. 
I know there is a term in mechanics which is proportional to the third derivative of position (rate of change of acceleration), but not sure in electronics.